# Object change notifications on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm following the example on the Google Cloud Platform documentation for [Object Change Notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Application_Example).

The bucket is owned by one application (`application-1`) and the App Engine app that should receive the notification is a separate application (`application-2`). Service accounts for both applications are Storage Object Admins for the bucket.

However, I am unable to create a notification channel for to watch the bucket. When I try to use `gsutil` to do so, an error is returned:

```
gsutil notification watchbucket https://application-2.appspot.com gs://bucket
Watching bucket gs://bucket/ with application URL https://application-2.appspot.com ...
ServiceException: 401 Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://appication-2.appspot.com
```

I have confirmed that the domain (`https://application-2.appspot.com`) is verified using the Search Console verification process and is configured as a webhook notification domain for both projects.

Answer (score 1):

I followed another set of [service account instructions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Authorization) to configure `gsutil` to use the service account, and that appears to have resolved the permissions error.

I created a new service account, though I used a JSON private key (the guide shows a p12 key being used). I then also had to assign Storage Legacy Bucket Owner permission to that service account for the particular bucket, re-authorize the webhook domain, and now watch notifications appear to be working.